# How to add sqlite to lumen?

Tags: php, sqlite, lumen

I would like to add sqlite db to my lumen app but I have some troubles.
I create migration:

> php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users

then I changed my .env file, so it looks like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite
```

then I was created database.sqlite and put it in storage folder and when I 'm trying to do:

> php artisan migrate

I have

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Database (database.sqlite) does not exist.

I uncommented this lines in bootstrap/app.php:

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
$app->withFacades();
```

I can't find what is wrong.

I work on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 9):

In my .env file I changed to:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
# DB_HOST=localhost
# DB_DATABASE=database.sqlite
```

I left only

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

So Lumen use default config from /vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php. It works.

Comment: with v5.4 default file location is /database/database.sqlite

Answer (score 5):

According to `lumen-framwork/config/database.php`

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', storage_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix'   => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
    ],
```

sqlite is the default setting for lumen.

And you can set `DB_CONNECTION` in `.env` as follows:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

Then lumen will use `storage_path('database.sqlite')` as `storage/database.sqlite`

---

Otherwise, if you would like to assign `DB_DATABASE` directly, you should give the full path:

```
DB_DATABASE=/Users/../../storage/database.sqlite
```

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1 :** Open **.env** file & replace respective database configuration with following piece of code.

```
DB_CONNECTION = sqlite    
#DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT = 3306
#DB_DATABASE = homestead
#DB_USERNAME = homestead
#DB_PASSWORD = secret
```

**Note :** lines those are started with **#** are basically commented code.

**Step 2 :** Create a new file, name it **database.sqlite** in database folder. It will store out database structure.

**Step 3 :** There is need to include this file as ignored in our versioning system as there will be so many changes are going to be made with database i.e. insert, delete, update etc.
 To ignore **database.sqlite**,
 Open **.gitignore** file, and add this line at the end `database/database.sqlite`. (i.e. path of database.sqlite file).